# Не адаптируется изображение в Mozilla

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

Почему не адаптируется изображение в Mozilla, верстаю Bootstrap, дал ему класс `img-responsive`?
В Chrome все хорошо, а вот в Mozilla печаль, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, может подсказать как быть?

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 right-form-block">
                        <img src="images/footer-logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        <div class="box col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <div class="map" id="map_canvas"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="adres-contacts-footer col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <p>г. Москва, ул. Большая Бронная, д. 27/</p>
                            <a href="#">+38 (050) 575-19-06</a><br>
                            <a href="#">+38 (093) 390-39-79</a><br>
                            <a href="#">+38 (067) 443-35-42</a><br>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А мне кажется, что это не из-за картинки, а из-за карты. Она не меняет размеры, а потому и ширина страницы остается неизменной, и картинка. не меняется. Проверьте меня - попробуйте карту убрать.

Comment: но в хроме то все адаптируется, проблема думаю не в этом, картинка сама по себе длинее карты, если было бы из-за карты, то она бы уменьшилась до размеров карты, и уже потом появлялся бы скролл с низу

Comment: Img {max-width: 100%; width:100%}